# converting from strings to ints

Tags: c++

I would like to know what is the easiest way to convert an int to C++ style string and from C++ style string to int.

*edit*

Thank you  very much. When converting form string to int what happens if I pass a char string ? (ex: "abce").

Thanks & Regards,

Mousey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to convert string to number.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int convert_string_to_number(const std::string& st)
{
    std::istringstream stringinfo(st);
    int num = 0;
    stringinfo >> num;
    return num;
}



int main()
{
    int  number = 0;

    std::string number_as_string("425");
    number = convert_string_to_number(number_as_string);

    std::cout << "The number is " << number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of digits are " << number_as_string.length() << std::endl;
}
```

Like wise, the following is to convert number to string.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string convert_number_to_string(const int& number_to_convert)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << number_to_convert;
    return (os.str());
}

int main()
{
    int number = 425;

    std::string stringafterconversion;
    stringafterconversion = convert_number_to_string(number);

    std::cout << "After conversion " << stringafterconversion << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of digits are " << stringafterconversion.length() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ick... `#include "stdafx.h"`?  You need the other three, but you can definitely do without `stdafx.h`. Oh, and `main` is supposed to return an integer.

Comment: @D. Shawley: c++ actually has a rule saying that `main` is a special case and may have the `return 0;` omitted resulting in the same effect as if you had put it there.

Comment: What happens if I call the first function like this: `convert_string_to_number("blah")`? As it is, this will silently fail and return the same as if I'd called `convert_string_to_number("0")`. That''s a definitive `-1` from me.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I voted up, it gets the point across just fine, even if the headers/main function is questionable.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @AshleysBrain: I wrote "That's a definitive `-1` from me" and write below that you come and ask "Why the downvote?" Frankly, I'm at a loss as to what to answer to that politely.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the *easiest* is to use `operator<<` and `operator>>` with a `stringstream` (you can initialize a `stringstream` from a `string`, and use the stream's `.str()` member to retrieve a string after writing to it.

Boost has a [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm?sess=40eeb38f681b328a276027a075cd91e8) that makes this particularly easy (though hardly a paragon of efficiency). Normal use would be something like `int x = lexical_cast<int>(your_string);`

Comment: But very readable (and well named) :-)  PS: referring to lexical_cast

Answer (score 1):

You can change "%x" specifier to "%d" or any other format supported by sprintf. Ensure to appropriately adjust the buffer size 'buf'

```
int main(){
        char buf[sizeof(int)*2 + 1];
        int x = 0x12345678;
        sprintf(buf, "%x", x);

        string str(buf);

        int y = atoi(str.c_str());
    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
int main(){
    char buf[sizeof(int)*2 + 1];
    int x = 42;
    sprintf(buf, "%x", x);

    string str(buf);

    //int y = atoi(str.c_str());
    int y = static_cast<int>(strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16));
}
```

Comment: assuming 4 bytes for integer, there will be 8 hex digits with the "%x" specifier.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  `sprintf(buf, "%x", 42);` puts "2a" into `buf`.  `atoi("2a")` is going to return `2` not `42`.

Comment: @D.Shawley: You caught me on that one. Have used strtol instead

Comment: while this is a functional solution, I try to steer developers who are clearly fairly new to the language right away from using unchecked fixed sized char arrays, its just asking for segfaults.

If performance is an issue, char's might be a better way to work but otherwise i'd be sticking with stringstreams

Answer (score -1):

Use `atoi` to convert a string to an int.  Use a `stringstream` to convert the other way.

Comment: If you want something on the order of `atoi`, at least use `strtol`, which can at least indicate when there's an error.